# MySQL table design and normalization assistance

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

Note: This question has been rephrased on 11/19/12 for clarification. I typically don't have much issue here but struggling designing a new product system for a client site. We offer a suite of products each client can sell to his customers. We may add new products at anytime but they all follow this format:

1. Category
2. Type
3. Product

To give a real world example using the structure from before:

- Baseball Equipment

  - Gloves

    - Rawlings
    - Nike
    - Mizzuno
  - Bats

    - Easton
    - Louisville Slugger
- Football Equipment

  - Shoes

    - Nike
    - Reebok
    - Adidas
  - Footballs

    - Nike
    - Saplding
    - Wilson
  ....

The list above clearly continues and can be much, much larger but it gives the overall idea.

Currently, I am storing the types of products particular clients can sell in a single flat format table as follows:

```
ID  | clientID | categoryID | typeID | productID | customURL
=============================================================
1   |  111     |    1       |   1    |   1       | 1111
2   |  111     |    1       |   2    |   2       | 2222
3   |  111     |    1       |   2    |   3       | 3333
4   |  111     |    2       |   3    |   4       | 4444
5   |  222     |    1       |   1    |   1       | 5555
6   |  222     |    2       |   3    |   4       | 6666
```

- In the example above, category 1 can be "baseball equipment" and category 2 is "football equipment"
- The names of the corresponding categoryID, typeID, and productID would be stored in 3 seaprate tables with FK relationships (innodb) so as to maintain normalization.
- the type refers to the second level items (gloves, bats, shoes, footballs, etc). These numbers never intersect (meaning there can never be the same typeID even if the general  product is the same (shoes in baseball has a separate id than shoes for football).
- In this table, clientID 1 can sell 4 products, 3 in category 1 and 1 in category 2. ClientID 2 can sell 2 products, one in each category.

I am inclined to keep the table as structured but know in other design I may have separated the tables for normalization purposes I am not sure that apply here. If I broke them out, I would see this going from one table to 4 or more as follows:

### productsOffered table

```
ID  | clientID | productID | customURL
======================================
1   |  111     | 1       | 1111
2   |  111     | 2       | 2222
3   |  111     | 3       | 3333
4   |  111     | 4       | 4444
5   |  222     | 1       | 5555
6   |  222     | 4       | 6666
```

### productsDefinition Table

```
ID  | productID | typeID | productName
======================================
1   |  1        |    1   | rawlings glove
2   |  2        |    2   | product2
3   |  3        |    2   | product3
4   |  4        |    3   | product4
```

### typeDefinition Table

```
ID  | typeID | categoryID | typeName
=====================================
1   |  1     |    1       | Gloves
2   |  2     |    1       | Bats
3   |  3     |    2       | Shoes
4   |  4     |    2       | Footballs
```

### categoriesDefinition Table

```
ID  | categoryID | catName
=============================
1   |  1         | Baseball Equipment
2   |  2         | Football Equipment
```

Am I over thinking this? Don't both methods get the end solution the same way (the latter just involves several joins to gather the flat table as shown in figure 1)?

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of what you're trying to accomplish, and I don't think you're going to accomplish anything by typing it out. I suggest revising this on paper/whiteboard as you'll be able to define groupings and relationships much easier.

Comment: @Sammitch - I'll reword to make more sense now with a real world example.

Comment: Read "The Kimball Group Reader" IMO. It does a great job explaining the basics of dimensional design and how to work it into a number of scenarios.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose and benefit of normalization is that it makes it harder (ideally, impossible) to enter anomalous data.

For example, in your figure 1, what's to prevent you from accidentally storing a row with typeid 3 and categoryid 1?  Nothing, besides writing application code that is absolutely perfect.

But if you use your single-table approach, and you ever have to change the parent category of typeid 3, you'd have to change the data in a million places to reflect the change.  This means locking the table while you perform that cleanup, or else new data could be inserted concurrently.

Normalization helps to eliminate storing information redundantly, and if every discrete fact (e.g. typeid 3 belongs to categoryid 2) is stored only once, then it's easy to make changes  atomically, and which automatically change the meaning of all references to that row.

You're right that more joins are needed -- but only if you use pseudokeys all over the place like you're doing.  You don't necessarily need to do that, you could use natural keys instead, and references to them would be declared with cascading foreign keys so a change in a lookup table automatically updates referencing tables too.

Certainly rules of *normalization* do not mandate using pseudokeys.  These rules say nothing about them.

---

Re your comment: a *pseudokey*, or [*surrogate key*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), is the "id" column that's used to identify rows.  Typically the values are allocated through an automatic incrementing mechanism that ensures uniqueness while allowing concurrent transactions to insert rows.  The value of an id has no meaning with respect to the row it identifies.

---

Below shows what your tables would look like in normal form, but without surrogate keys.

### productsOffered table

```
client | product        | customURL
===================================
Smith  | Rawlings Glove | 1111
Smith  | Product 2      | 2222
Smith  | Product 3      | 3333
Smith  | Product 4      | 4444
Jones  | Rawlings Glove | 5555
Jones  | Product 4      | 6666
```

### productsDefinition Table

```
product        | type
=======================
Rawlings Glove | Gloves
Product 2      | Bats
Product 3      | Bats
Product 4      | Shoes
```

### typeDefinition Table

```
type      | category
==============================
Gloves    | Baseball Equipment
Bats      | Baseball Equipment
Shoes     | Football Equipment
Footballs | Football Equipment
```

### categoriesDefinition Table

```
category
==================
Baseball Equipment
Football Equipment
```

It's perfectly in keeping with relational database design and normalization to use non-integers as the data type for a primary key column, and therefore the foreign keys referencing them from other tables.

There are good reasons to use surrogate keys, for the sake of performance or brevity or allowing the values in other columns to change freely.  But *normalization* does not mandate using surrogate keys.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I am not too familiar with the term "pseudokey". Can you provide reference? I'll be creating indexes on the id lookup columns in each of the tables and create FK relationships between the IDs of each table to the master. The one thing does DOES do however, is prevent me from having say one type ID applicable to multiple category IDS (if the design requirements of the program ever change)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the normalised approach, as you have to maintain separate lookup tables for category and type names (and possibly other attributes) with the flat approach anyway.

You might consider changing the category and type into a general tree structure using a table such as:

```
 create table product_hierarchy(
    id integer primary key,
    name character,
    parent_id references product_hierarchy)
```

... as it would give the client the flexibility to add more depth to the hierarchy.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I typically try and stay away from hierarchy situations with MySQL since it does not support full recursion but may have to consider it here.

Comment: valid suggestion for the future but I have never used it and have no time to be learning it along with server implementation and security around PostgreSQL in place of MySQL at this time.

Answer (score 1):

To try to address your direct questions:

> Am I over thinking this?

Depends on how big your application is going to be, and what engine you're using for storing the data.  Since you're planning on putting it into MySQL tables, your thoughts are very appropriate.

> Don't both methods get the end solution the same way (the latter just
>   involves several joins to gather the flat table as shown in figure 1)?

Well, yes, but to [quote Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization),

> Database normalization is the process of organizing the fields and
>   tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency.
>   Normalization usually involves dividing large tables into smaller (and
>   less redundant) tables and defining relationships between them. The
>   objective is to isolate data so that additions, deletions, and
>   modifications of a field can be made in just one table and then
>   propagated through the rest of the database via the defined
>   relationships.

Breaking your data out into the structure you described (which I agree with, by the way), will allow you to most easily maintain your data.  Keeping the category and type data in the same table as the "products offered" creates a lot of redundant data.  Granted, I can't really imagine where you'd need to update that data, but if you did, you'd have to update a lot of records.  In your proposed structure, the number of records to be updated is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach you forgot the name column for each category, type and product id. If you add this information it can work but the other approach seems to work already. When you use 4 different tables you have more space.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I would have this information stored in separate tables so as not to waste space of a table and for normalization. Table 1 *could* be normalized if the names of categories, products, and types were all stored in separate tables

Comment: The main "issue" I see here really is that to achieve the full flat table result (in first table), I'd be doing several joins as opposed to have it built that way in the first place. I know this may or may not pass normalization principles and hence my dilemma.

Comment: The 2nd approach is better. Read the answer from David. Also many small tables can hold more data. There may be issue with importing data and data exchange but like you said you can use some joins to solve it.